How to force resource string from library over the same resource name defined in the app
I have an Android app that uses a library and both have string resources with identical names (but with different values). Apps will override and use the app's version and ignore the library's version if names are identical as far as I know.
From the app:
    <string name="hello">Hello from App</string>

From the library:
    <string name="hello">Hello from Library</string>

I have code in the library that calls context.getString(R.string.hello) and when the App is run I want it to take the value from the library (Hello from Library) instead of the App's version of the value. However, I only get the app's version.
How do I ensure the library uses ONLY the library's version?
I have tried using the same namespace in build gradle (under the android section) and package in the library's manifest
android {
    namespace = "com.library.ui"
}

and
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.library.ui">
</manifest>

Is there a way I can achieve this without having to manually adding a prefix to all string resources in the library?

Since it is your app, wouldn't it be easier to rename the resource in the app to something that does not conflict?

@CommonsWare renaming/prefixing the IDs in the library is a possibility for me and I can do that. I just wondered if there is a way the library can deterministically use its own resource ids irrespective of what has been declared at the app level. I tried using getString from createPackageContext and passed the library package name but that approach did not work either.

"renaming/prefixing the IDs in the library is a possibility for me" -- I suggested renaming/prefixing the ID in the app, not the library. You open with "I have an Android app", so we are going to assume that you control the source of the app. It would seem like you only need to change the one or two resources in the app that collide with the library, as it would be rather unusual for the app and library to wind up accidentally with a lot of identical resource IDs. Are we misunderstanding the situation?

@CommonsWare sorry if was not clear before. Both app and library are in our control. We have a situation where there is going to be a certain amount of overlap of code between these two short term and will be resolved over a period of time. Changing library is relatively easier. As of now, same strings IDs have different values in certain cases and that's why I wanted to know if there is a way to qualify the IDs coming from library.

Ah, OK. I recall Google making some moves in the direction of giving libraries their own resource namespace 6-7 years ago, but I forget where they wound up with that. What you're describing is classic Android behavior: there is a single resource namespace, and apps' resources take precedence.
